# Best practice on using a generic linked list for a specific queue implementation

Tags: c#, queue, private, singly-linked-list

I was trying a practice problem and have implemented a generic Singly Linked List in C# whose head is a private variable -

```
/// <summary>
/// Root of the linked list
/// </summary>
private Node head;
```

---

```
public class Node
{
    private object data;
    private Node next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Data contained in the node
    /// </summary>
    public object Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }

        set
        {
            data = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the next node of the singly linked list
    /// </summary>
    public Node Next
    {
        get
        {
            return next;
        }

        set
        {
            next = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to solve another problem where I need to implement a FIFO queue using this singly linked list for a cat and dog shelter. This queue should allow dequeueing the last enqueued cat/dog but additionally also two methods -

DequeueCat - Dequeue oldest cat even if it isn't the last node of the queue

DequeueDog - Dequeue oldest dog even if it isn't the last node of the queue

I didn't want to implement these methods in the SinglyLinkedList class but create a separate class named CatDogShelterQueue -

But for implementing the DequeueCat/Dog methods, I'd need to traverse the linkedlist and reach the oldest Cat/Dog node.

I know of a few ways in which to do this -

1. Make 'head' `protected` instead of `private` and inherit SinglyLinkedList as the base class of CatDogShelterQueue
2. Make 'head' `internal` and use it by referencing a variable of SinglyLinkedList type -

`private SinglyLinkedList queue;`

For now, I chose the second option but wanted to know what is best practice in situations like these.

My final current solution is below -

**SinglyLinkedList**

```
/*  Program: Singly Linked List implementation in C#
 *  
 *  Date: 12/24/2015
 */

using System;

namespace CrackingTheCodingInterview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A node of the singly linked list
    /// It contains data in generic object type and points to next node in the list
    /// </summary>
    public class Node
    {
        private object data;
        private Node next;

        /// <summary>
        /// Data contained in the node
        /// </summary>
        public object Data
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }

            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reference to the next node of the singly linked list
        /// </summary>
        public Node Next
        {
            get
            {
                return next;
            }

            set
            {
                next = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of a singly linked list
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SinglyLinkedList
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Root of the linked list
        /// </summary>
        internal Node head;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new node for inserting in singly linked list
        /// <param name="d">Data to be inserted in node</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the created node to be added in singly linked list</returns>
        /// </summary>
        private Node CreateNewNode(object d)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.Data = d;
            newNode.Next = null;

            return newNode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor of singly linked list
        /// </summary>
        public SinglyLinkedList()
        {
            head = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert a node to the start of singly linked list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">Data to be inserted in the singly linked list</param>
        public void Insert(object d)
        {
            Node newNode = CreateNewNode(d);

            if (head == null)
            {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode.Next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Traverse and print all the nodes of singly linked list
        /// </summary>
        public void Print()
        {
            Node temp = head;

            while (temp != null)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}->", temp.Data);
                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <param name="d">Data to be searched in all the nodes of a singly linked list</param>
        /// Traverses through each node of a singly linked list and searches for an element
        /// <returns>Node if the searched element exists else null </returns>
        /// </summary>
        public Node Search(object d)
        {
            Node temp = head;

            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (temp.Data.Equals(d))
                {
                    return temp;
                }

                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns head of the linked list if it exists else null
        /// <returns>Data in head of linked list if it exists else null</returns>
        /// </summary>
        public object DeleteHead()
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                Node temp = head;
                head = head.Next;

                return temp.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Peeks head of the linked list if it exists else null
        /// <returns>Data in head of linked list if it exists else null</returns>
        /// </summary>
        public object PeekHead()
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                return head.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the singly linked list is empty
        /// <returns>true if linked list is empty else false</returns>
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return (head == null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts the element at the end of the linked list
        /// <param name="d">Element to be inserted at the end</param>
        /// </summary>
        public void InsertEnd(object d)
        {
            Node newNode = CreateNewNode(d);

            Node temp = head;

            if (head == null)
            {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                while (temp.Next != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }

                temp.Next = newNode;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the last node of the linked list
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Last node of linked list</returns>
        public object DeleteEnd()
        {
            if (head == null || head.Next == null)
            {
                return DeleteHead();
            }
            else
            {
                Node temp = head;

                while (temp.Next.Next != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Next;
                }

                object del = temp.Next.Data;
                temp.Next = null;
                return del;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes second last element of linked list
        /// <returns>Second last element of linked list</returns>
        /// </summary>
        public object DeleteSecondLast()
        {
            if (head == null || head.Next == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (head.Next.Next == null)
                {
                    object del = head.Data;
                    head = head.Next;

                    return del;
                }
                else
                {
                    Node temp = head;

                    while (temp.Next.Next.Next != null)
                    {
                        temp = temp.Next;
                    }

                    object del = temp.Next.Data;
                    temp = temp.Next.Next;

                    return del;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CatDogShelterQueue**

```
/*  Program: To implement a queue for cat and dog shelter
 *  
 *  Date: 1/1/2016
 */

using System;

namespace CrackingTheCodingInterview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for a cat and dog shelter queue
    /// </summary>
    public class CatDogShelterQueue
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Class for storing type and number of cat/dog
        /// </summary>
        public class CatDog
        {
            internal CatDogType type;

            internal int num;

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for initializing CatDog with its type and number
            /// </summary>
            public CatDog(int n, CatDogType t)
            {
                num = n;
                type = t;
            }
        }

        private SinglyLinkedList queue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor initializing a singly linked list acting as a FIFO queue
        /// </summary>
        public CatDogShelterQueue()
        {
            queue = new SinglyLinkedList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <param name="d"> Cat/Dog Number </param>
        /// <param name="c"> Type - Cat or Dog </param>
        /// </summary>
        public void enqueue(object d, CatDogType c)
        {
            CatDog cd = new CatDog((int)d, c);

            queue.Insert(cd);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dequeueing last animal - cat or dog
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Cat or Dog oldest arrival</returns>
        public CatDog dequeueAny()
        {
            return (CatDog)queue.DeleteEnd();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dequeueing the oldest cat
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Oldest entered cat</returns>
        public CatDog dequeueCat()
        {
            Node lastCat = null;

            Node temp = queue.head;

            while(temp != null)
            {
                if (((CatDog)temp.Data).type == CatDogType.Cat)
                {
                    lastCat = temp;
                }

                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            if(lastCat.Next == null)
            {
                return (CatDog)queue.DeleteEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                CatDog del = (CatDog)lastCat.Data;
                lastCat.Data = lastCat.Next.Data;
                lastCat.Next = lastCat.Next.Next;

                return del;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dequeueing the oldest dog
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Oldest entered dog</returns>
        public CatDog dequeueDog()
        {
            Node lastCat = null;

            Node temp = queue.head;

            while (temp != null)
            {
                if (((CatDog)temp.Data).type == CatDogType.Dog)
                {
                    lastCat = temp;
                }

                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            if (lastCat.Next == null)
            {
                return (CatDog)queue.DeleteEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                CatDog del = (CatDog)lastCat.Data;
                lastCat.Data = lastCat.Next.Data;
                lastCat.Next = lastCat.Next.Next;

                return del;
            }
        }
    }

    internal class CatDogShelterQueueTest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            CatDogShelterQueue q = new CatDogShelterQueue();

            q.enqueue(1, CatDogType.Cat);
            q.enqueue(2, CatDogType.Dog);
            q.enqueue(3, CatDogType.Cat);
            q.enqueue(4, CatDogType.Dog);
            q.enqueue(5, CatDogType.Cat);

            Console.WriteLine("Dequeueing last animal: {0}", q.dequeueAny().num);
            Console.WriteLine("Dequeueing last cat: {0}", q.dequeueCat().num);
            Console.WriteLine("Dequeueing last dog: {0}", q.dequeueDog().num);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cat or Dog
    /// </summary>
    public enum CatDogType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Cat
        /// </summary>
        Cat,

        /// <summary>
        /// Dog
        /// </summary>
        Dog
    };
}
```

Comment: Generally CodeReview.StackExchange.com is better place to get feedback on working code. I'm not exactly sure what specific feedback you are looking from SO. Personally I  neither of 2 options to deal with `head` you've listed are significantly better (think both are bad, but  that is personal opinion).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Alexei. Let me try checking codereview.stackexchange.com. Didn't know about it :) I also feel both approaches are hacky. So wanted to know best practice.

Comment: Code Review may be a fit for your question, just make sure: (A) **Your question is working, non-hypothetical code** (B) **You read the on-topic guide before posting**